# Is there a way to specify version of Oracle Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

Today we are working with two versions of Oracle 12c and 11g. The development is performed in version 12c.

When using Entity to perform a count, it is applying a function that does not exist in version 11g "OUTER APPLY".

Is there any way to configure the entity so that it understands which version of oracle the database is in? Or even be it so that you always use the 11g version?

Thanks in advance.

I already tried to update the version. Also I did not find anything that could define the oracle database version

Error = Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 does not support APPLY;

Comment: The following link might help you https://shazwazza.com/post/multi-targeting-a-single-net-project-to-build-for-different-framework-versions/